# SQL join that not in grouped date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this user_activity table

```
user_id   date
1         2020-01-01 08:00:00
2         2020-01-01 08:05:00
1         2020-01-02 08:00:00
```

and user table

```
user_id
1
2
3
```

I want to know the user that don't have activity on all date. like this

```
date        user_id
2020-01-01  3
2020-01-02  2
2020-01-02  3
```

I'm trying this but can't figure it out how to grouped it with date

```
SELECT a.* FROM user_activity a
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u on a.user_id= u.user_id
where a.user_id is null
```

I already looking for the answer but there is no answer with grouped date

Comment: How do you determine what "*all dates*" actually are?

Comment: date that contains on user activity

Comment: Do you mean on all dates that are present in your `user_activity` table? Or every day from earliest to the latest day from the same table? Or would you have a separate table just for dates?

Comment: all dates that are present in my user_activity table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_id, all_dates.date
FROM user u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) as date FROM user_activity) as all_dates
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM user_activity ua
  WHERE ua.user_id = u.user_id
    AND DATE(ua.date) = all_dates.date
)
```

->

```
user_id     date
3           2020-01-01
3           2020-01-02
2           2020-01-02
```

Also created a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c6102a389276799e2fec8c4a6ad3099d) for you to play with